# How does the performance of a Multidimensional array compare to an array of objects?

Tags: c++, performance

Say I have 3 values:

```
int age;
int girth;
int length;
```

Would it be more efficient to store and loop through these values in a multidimensional array OR to declare a class with these 3 member variables and then fill an array with objects of this class?

Comment: It probably won't be much different. To be sure, run some tests.

Comment: Exactly the same. Either way the compiler has to generate a multiplication to generate he correct index.

Comment: Structure may be easier to wrangle and visualize, and since it will be a 1D array the data will be contiguous. If you try the old `int **` trick to make a dynamic 2D array (an array of arrays) you may run into problems with cache misses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interpret every dimension as one of your values, it will be ok for the small array sizes. Despite that, when you will fall out of cache, you will probably experience huge decrease in performance if you want to access first element of the first dimension, then of the second and third dimensions. It is due to memory layout of multi dimensional arrays and CPU caching.

If you'll have it as a struct or all 3 values are interpreted as one dimension of the array, and If you will keep accessing that array in traversal manner (e.g. not jumping around), then you will get probably the best performance possible.

So, it should be like this:

```
struct entry
{
    int age;
    int girth;
    int length;
}

std::array<entry, /*size*/> entries;
```